# Bootstrap: list-inline with bullets?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

Anybody knows, how to add bullets/separators between elements in horizontal list in Bootstrap 3?

```
<ul class="list-inline">
   <li>Author: Michal</li>
   <li>Modified: 17.08.2014</li>
   <li>Comments: 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thy this CSS:

```
.list-inline{display:block;}
.list-inline li{display:inline-block;}
.list-inline li:after{content:'|'; margin:0 10px;}
```

you can see [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a163wsba/).

Needless to say you can use anything you want instead of a pipe separator, this is just an example

Comment: Thanks! It works, but how to remove bullet from last element?

Comment: .list-inline li:last-child:after {content: '';}

Comment: what about list-style properties ?

Comment: Or you could do this: .list-inline li:not(:last-child):after{content:'\2022'; margin:0 10px;}

Answer (score 8):

You could use `&bull;`

```
<ul class="list-inline">
   <li>&bull; Author: Michal</li>
   <li>&bull; Modified: 17.08.2014</li>
   <li>&bull; Comments: 5</li>
</ul>
```

Or you could use icons like [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), a bullet icon would be `<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an scss version for a variation on bootstrap 3's `.list-inline` I've named `.list-inline-separated` (using bullets):

```
.list-inline-separated {
  @extend .list-inline;

  li {
    // adjust leading spacing for each additional item
    margin-left: -10px;

    &:first-child {

      // no leading spacing for initial item
      margin-left: 0px;
    }

    &:after {
      content: '\2022'; // bullet
      margin: 0 5px;
    }

    // no bullet on last
    &:last-child:after {
      content: '';
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good...