# inline bullet in rmarkdown

Tags: html, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to make an inline bullet.

```
* my first bullet, * my second bullet,...
```

The expected Answer is an inline version of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084904/r-markdown-bullet-list-with-multiple-levels).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap: list-inline with bullets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353955/bootstrap-list-inline-with-bullets)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to put the `<ul>` and `<li>` HTML tags to create a bullet list in one line:

```
<ul><li>One, <li>Two, <li>Tree<ul>
```

Live example:

- One,

  Two,

  Tree

Or in multiple lines:

```
* One <br> - Two <br> - Tree
```

Live examples:

- One 
   - Two 
   - Tree

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `text_spec()` e.g.

```
`r kableExtra::text_spec("• my first bullet,  • my second bullet")`
```